# How to call a where on a polymorphic association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I three models like this which have a polymorphic association :

Main model :

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: packages
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string
#  price      :money
#  plan_id    :integer
#  plan_type  :string
#  active     :boolean          default(FALSE)
#  order      :integer
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :plan, polymorphic: true
    monetize :price
end
```

One child :

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: timepackages
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  months     :integer
#  downloads  :integer
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class Timepackage < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :package, as: :plan, dependent: :destroy
end
```

I need to get all the `Timepackages` which have a `months` value of 1. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Timepackage.where(:months => 1)
```

I don't see how the polymorphic relationship referred to in your question's title comes into the requirements listed in your actual question.

Comment: Wow...that's super basic rails, dude.  Did you try googling before stackoverflow?